# React useEffect every 5 seconds with setInterval- first render

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I'm trying to rerender my component every 5 seconds. The problem occurs when I open the page the first time- it shows after 5 seconds. How should I make sure to make my component visible instantly after page is opened?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getChargersData = () => {
      axios.get(API_URL)
        .then(res => {
          setChargers(res.data);
        })
    }

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      getChargersData()
    },5*1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  },[]);
```

Comment: Do i understand correctly: you want to call getChargersData right away when the component mounts, and then also call it every 5 seconds after that? If so, add `getChargersData()` to the body of your useEffect (either before the interval or after)

Comment: @NicholasTower yes, thanks. I don't know why I didn't think of that. I somehow thought the function will render twice every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call the getChargerData function before the setInterval, this way the data will be available before the first 5s ellapse

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getChargersData = () => {
      axios.get(API_URL)
        .then(res => {
          setChargers(res.data);
        })
    }
    getChargersData()
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      getChargersData()
    },5*1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  },[]);
```